# Displaying DataView in DataGrid hello world

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

Simple hello world - trying to display `DataView` in `DataGrid`.  What do I need to add?  The DataGrid in the resulting window as nothing in it.

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public DataView Displayed
        {
            get
            {
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                table.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(string));
                table.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(string));
                table.Columns.Add("Col3", typeof(string));

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                    row["Col1"] = i.ToString() + "col1";
                    row["Col2"] = i.ToString() + "col2";
                    row["Col3"] = i.ToString() + "col3";
                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                }

                return table.DefaultView;
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```xaml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <toolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Displayed, Mode=OneWay}"> 
        </toolkit:DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Output window:

```
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'c:\users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WpfApplication3\WpfApplication3\bin\Debug\WpfApplication3.vshost.exe', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0x1dac) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1990) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x824) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'c:\users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WpfApplication3\WpfApplication3\bin\Debug\WpfApplication3.exe', Symbols loaded.
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'WpfApplication3.App.App'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'WpfApplication3.App.InitializeComponent'
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'c:\users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WpfApplication3\WpfApplication3\bin\Debug\WPFToolkit.dll'
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication3.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

Result:

[image: Result screenshot showing empty DataGrid]

I want to see the data defined in `Displayed` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `DataContext` of `MainWindow` to itself. Otherwise `Displayed` will not be found.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

Same in XAML

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```